# Handle specific exception that is not related to an exchange

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I created a custom component for a proprietary service. If this service is down i get noticed via a call of a callback function. I am throwing a custom exception at this point.

Sending exchanges to the producer/ consumer will yield no errors or exceptions (all seems to fine).

So i need to implement an emergency stop if my custom exception is thrown. I read a bit about exception handling in camel. I think i need a context-scoped `onException(MyException.class).???` but what then?

Is this working on exceptions that are called without relation to an exchange? If this is working how to handle it. I want to stop certain routes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find to stop routes from a route: http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html.
If you do the call of the proprietary service in a route you do have an exchange btw.

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: "If you do the call of the proprietary service in a route you do have an exchange btw" -> no only if process is called and the exception is thrown within process. In my case the exception is thrown in a callback method that is called by the service - no exchange is involved and therefore "onException" isn't working. The problem is not how to stop the route but to get camel to handle the exception.

Comment: Can you call a route in case of your custom exception(or instead of the exception)? In this route you can stop the routes that should be stopped(with camel control bus for example).

Answer (score 0):

I created a little workaround: I set a boolean i the callback method is called. On each call of process i check this boolean and if true i throw an exception.
With this the exception is within normal camel exception handling and onException could be used.